# Ora 01017: Invalid Username/Password using Oracle SQL Developer OS Authentication

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded Oracle SQL Developer from Oracle website. I have extracted the files in C: drive and executing the program from there. I am trying to connect to a database using TNS which is successful when using SYS login. I then created a user as per my AD login "DOMAIN\USERNAME" and given proper roles , access etc. When I try to create a new Connection in SQL Developer using OS Authentication, I get the Ora 01017 error. This login is set to "identified externally"

However, if I use the SQL Developer that comes with Oracle 11G Client then it works well for OS Authent. I want to use the latest SQL Developer with OS Authen I downloaded but stuck as it gives the ora01017 error.

has anyone seen issue like this? also what would be the recommended setting for remote_os_authent and sec_case_sensitive_logon in case these are causing the issue?

Comment: Did you got the solution? even i'm facing the same problem

Comment: Hi, our DBA used TNS_ADMIN system variable which was using some sort of global TNSNames.ora file. The sqlnet.ora file that resides in the same directory had this "SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)" which should have been "SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)". Please check your local sqlnet.ora file for that.

Comment: You can also define the path to your TNSNames.ora file when using SQL Developer. Go to Tools-Preferences-expand Database node-click on Advanced- then you will notice a filed called "Tnsnames Directory". You can navigate to your the folder containing Tnsnames.ora and supply the path here. Restart SQlLDeveloper and see if it works.